# Access name of the object that "i" represents when it iterates in a for-loop through a list of objects in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, objectname

I have:

- directories (let's say two: A and B) that contain files;
- two character objects storing the directories (`dir_A`, `dir_B`);
- a function that takes the directory as argument and returns the list of the names of the files found there (in a convenient way for me that is different from `list.files()`).

```
directories <- c(dir_A, dir_B)
read_names <- function(x) {foo}
```

Using a for-loop, I want to create objects that each contain the list of files of a different directory as given by `read_names()`. Essentially, I want to use a for-loop to do the equivalent as:

```
files_A <- read_names(dir_A)
files_B <- read_names(dir_B)
```

I wrote the loop as follows:

```
for (i in directories) {
  assign(paste("files_", sub('.*\\_', '', deparse(substitute(i))), sep = ""), read_names(i))
}
```

However, although outside of the for-loop `deparse(substitute(dir_A))` returns "dir_A" (and, consequently, the `sub()` function written as above would return "A"), it seems to me that in the for-loop `substitute(i)` makes `i` stop being one of the directories, and just being `i`.

It follows that `deparse(substitute(i))` returns `"i"` and that the output of the for-loop above is only one object called `files_i`, which contains the list of the files in the last directory of the iteration because that is the last one that has been overwritten on `files_i`.

How can I make the for-loop read the name (or part of the name in my case, but it is the same) of the object that `i` is representing in that moment?

Comment: After you write `directories <- c(dir_A, dir_B)` there is no tie to the variable `dir_A`, only the value of `dir_A` at the time that you executed the statement creating directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here, I think:

1. How to reference both the name (or index) and the value of each element within a `list`; and
2. How to transfer data from a named `list` into the global (or any) environment.

---

## 1. Reference name/index with data

Once you index with `for (i in directories)`, the full context (index, name) of `i` within `directories` is lost. Some alternatives:

```r
for (ix in seq_along(directories)) {
   directories[[ix]]             # the *value*
   names(directories)[ix]        # the *name*
   ix                            # the *index*
   # ...
}

for (nm in names(directories)) {
   directories[[nm]]             # the *value*
   nm                            # the *name*
   match(nm, names(directories)) # the *index*
   # ...
}
```

If you're amenable to `Map`-like functions (a more idiomatic way of dealing with lists of similar things), then

```r
out <- Map(function(x, nm) {
  x                              # the *value*
  nm                             # the *name*
   # ...
}, directories, names(directories))

out <- purrr::imap(directories, function(x, nm) {
  x                              # the *value*
  nm                             # the *name*
   # ...
})
# there are other ways to identify the function in `purrr::` functions
```

Note: while it is quite easy to use `match` within these last two to get the index, it is a minor *scope-breach* that I prefer to avoid when reasonable. It works, I just prefer alternative methods. If you want the value, name, *and* index, then

```r
out <- Map(function(x, nm, ix) {
  x                              # the *value*
  nm                             # the *name*
  ix                             # the *index*
   # ...
}, directories, names(directories), seq_along(directories))
```

---

## 2. Transfer list to env

In your question, you're doing this to assign variables within a list into another environment. Some thoughts on *that* effort:

1. If they are all similar (the same *structure*, different *data*), then **Don't**. Keep them in a `list` and work on them en toto using `lapply` or similar. ([How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207))
2. If you truly need to move them from a list to the global environment, then perhaps `list2env` is useful here.

   ```r
   # create my fake data
   directories <- list(a=1, b=2)
   # this is your renaming step, rename before storing in the global env
   # ... not required unless you have no names or want/need different names
   names(directories) <- paste0("files_", names(directories))
   # here the bulk of the work; you can safely ignore the return value
   list2env(directories, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   # <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
   ls()
   # [1] "directories" "files_a"     "files_b"    
   files_a
   # [1] 1
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to coding so I'll need to take a bit of time to really understand everything that your reasoning implies. In the meanwhile I tried to solve it with the `names(directories)` trick, but the function kept returning `NULL` (also when I tried it with sample dummy objects). But often it is key just to get the job done, so I found a workaround doing `names_directories <- sort(grep("dir_", (names(environment()), value = TRUE)` and then using `names_directories[i]` inside `paste()` in the loop. Maybe not the most efficient, but ok for now. Also @G5W helped me realise.

Comment: `names(directories)` of `NULL` means it has no names.

Comment: Yes, now I understand the point - however this to me looks like only changing place to the problem. If I have only two directories, then I can go `directories <- c(dir_A = dir_A, dir_B = dir_B)`. However if I want to automate the process then I fall back on the same issue. But I guess that this less about the original question and more about me getting to grips with R and programming. Anyway, I was thinking again about this and realised that in some sense I could just not bother about creating these objects and just keep using the `read_names()` when needed - which maybe is your last point.